# How to convert floating point number to string with escape character (for class selector)

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I wanna generate class selector from mixin, pass floating number to `rem`
And then convert float to string with escape character
such as `1.6` to be `1\.6`

### Expected Output

```css
.u-text-1\.6 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
}
```

### Example mixin

```css
@mixin utility-text-size($font-rem, $line-height-rem) {
  .u-text-#{<how-to-convert-font-rem?>} {
    font-size: #{$font-rem}rem;
    line-height: #{$line-height-rem}rem;
  }

  .\!u-text-#{<how-to-convert-font-rem?>} {
    font-size: #{$font-rem}rem !important;
    line-height: #{$line-height-rem}rem !important;
  }
}

@include utility-text-size(1.6, 2.4);
```

How can I finish it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the amazing **str-replace-function** written by Kitty Giraudel and available on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/str-replace-function/).

You'll look for the substring `.` and replace it with `\.`

```
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);
  
  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }
  
  @return $string;
}

@mixin utility-text-size($font-rem, $line-height-rem) {
    $escapedString : str-replace($font-rem + '', '.', \.);
    .u-text-#{$escapedString} {
        font-size: #{$font-rem}rem;
        line-height: #{$line-height-rem}rem;
    }
}

@include utility-text-size(1.6, 2.4);
```